# Examples of geospatial scientific posters

Tags: cartography, visualisation

Can you point me to examples of interesting scientific posters featuring results of geospatial analysis and/or geovisualizations?

Comment: See Tufts GIS Poster Expo for some inspiration https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/GISatTufts/Tufts+GIS+Poster+Expo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most GIS scientific posters will come out of either Universities or State GIS conferences.  Here are two examples:

[The Ohio GIS Conference has a yearly poster/map gallery that delinates between General, Analytical, and Communicative categories (2010 link).](http://ogrip.oit.ohio.gov/Events/PreviousOhioGISConferences/2010OhioGISConferenceMapGallery.aspx)

[Brown University](http://www.brown.edu/Research/Earthlab/research_posters.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Look on http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/FOSS4G_2009_Posters for some examples. Unfortunately, I don't found posters examples for the FOSS4G 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to browse on FOSS4G conference pages. They usually have poster session, like this one [FOSS4G Europe 2015](http://europe.foss4g.org/2015/Program).

Comment: True, but not really very different to the existing answer by Thomas77.

Comment: I know, but this link is updated with recent posters. But I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

May I add this website that ESRI has their Map Book Gallary. It has Online, Map Book archive ? Sometimes when I need something to look at, I usually go this site and to look at them.

http://www.esri.com/mapmuseum

There is another one not only for International but in United States as well..

http://icaci.org/

Comment: Plenty of good resources there.. however I do not think they would qualify as scientific posters..